# How to get rid of adjustedContentInset in UIWebview?

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, uiwebview

I have a `UIWebView` in which i load content from remote URL. Problem i am facing is, last part of the content of webview is not scrollable. When debugging i noticed that `adjustedContentInset` is set as `{0, 0, 49, 0}`. Perhaps that is the reason partial webview content(49 pts from end) is not scrollable. Is there any way i can get rid of `adjustedContentInset` so that the whole content becomes scrollable?

I tried setting the `contentInsets` of webview's scrollview to {0,0,0,0} but it didn't help.

`UITableView` and `UICollectionView` has `contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior` method to reset `adjustedContentInset` but i couldn't find such property for `UIWebView`.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Actually, [`contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiscrollview/2902261-contentinsetadjustmentbehavior) is a `UIScrollView` property, that's why what you mentioned:

> `UITableView` and `UICollectionView` has `contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior`
>   method to reset adjustedContentInset but i couldn't find such property
>   for `UIWebView`.

is correct.

That means `contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior` is *not* a property for the `UIWebView` (`UIView`), what would you need to do is to access it via the web view [`scrollView`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiwebview/1617955-scrollview) property:

> The scroll view associated with the web view.
>
> **Discussion**
>
> *Your app can access the scroll view if it wants to customize the
>   scrolling behavior of the web view.*

which exactly what are you aiming to. Therefore:

```
webView.scrollView.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = ...
```

should work.

Comment: If you see the documentaion `adjustedContentInset` of `UIScrollView` is readonly property. Hence `webView.scrollView.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = ..` will not work.

Comment: Referring to the property url: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiscrollview/2902261-contentinsetadjustmentbehavior, you can see it declared as: `var contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior: UIScrollViewContentInsetAdjustmentBehavior { get set }` which means you can set a value to it :) For instance, you could implement `webView.scrollView.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = .never`

Comment: Oh yes! Missed that out. I was looking at some other property. Thanks anyways, it worked.